# unset session php

Tags: php

According to the manual "Do NOT unset the whole $_SESSION with unset($_SESSION) as this will **disable the registering of session variables** through the $_SESSION superglobal."

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['name'] = 'my_name';

unset($_SESSION);

echo $_SESSION['test'] = 'ok';
```

So according to the manual, the above code should not register the last statement. But the code outputs the string 'ok'. What is going on here?

Comment: "It won't set variable" != "you can't set variable"

Comment: once you have unset the session, it is free to have new values stored in it, its not like it goes away forever. Unset merely clears the current values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't disable sessions. It simply disables the use of session_register. This is not a big deal, as session_register has been deprecated for a long time:

e.g. with this code:

```
<?php

$foo = 'bar';
session_register('foo');
print_r($_SESSION);
unset($_SESSION);
session_register('foo', 'bar2');
print_r($_SESSION);               // line 8
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar3';
print_r($_SESSION);
```

you get

```
Array
(
    [foo] =>
)
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: _SESSION in /home/marc/z.php on line 8
Array
(
    [foo] => bar3
)
```

note the warning. You've unset $_SESSION, then try to session_register... but this doesn't create a NEW $_SESSION, it simply fails.

Answer (score 1):

This is a better testcase:

```php
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 'value';
unset($_SESSION);
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

This code however, will output 'something' because you assign it just before echoing.

```
echo $_SESSION['something'] = 'something';
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what it means is that `$_SESSION['test']` will not automatically be saved in the session any more. If you print `$_SESSION['name']` on another page, it should be `myname`, but `$_SESSION['test']` should be empty.